# Shared Element Transition lags while opening

Tags: android, kotlin, shared-element-transition

[Check this please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqDnB.png)I am using glide to load image, and simple shared element transition animation but it lags while opening, i made correct use of supportPostponeEnterTransition() and supportStartPostponedEnterTransition()
as shown below in code.

```
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_order)
    supportPostponeEnterTransition()

    var extras = intent.extras
    var imgUrl = extras.getString("imgopen")
 var imgTranitionName = extras.getString("xyz")
    cafeImg.transitionName = imgTranitionName
    Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).thumbnail(0.01f).apply(RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)).listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable>{
        override fun onLoadFailed(
            e: GlideException?,
            model: Any?,
            target: Target<Drawable>?,
            isFirstResource: Boolean
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?,isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
               supportStartPostponedEnterTransition()

            return false
        }


    }).into(ImgView)
```

Comment: It's would be hard to figure out the source of lag since it may be originating from multiple sources. Maybe are you running some intensive task on the UI thread, or layout tree is extensive(inflation takes more time). In your `onCreate` of your View, write this code `StrictMode.enableDefaults()`. Log the details and include it in the question.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad logs arent showing up , PS: I dont know how to use it?

Comment: Have you opened Logcat and searched for "StrictMode"? Make sure to write that code in onCreate.

Comment: Yes , Dont know why arent logs coming up?

Comment: @TaseerAhmad i have posted a screenshot in my question description please have a look over it!

Comment: delete StrictMode string from filter and then share your logcat outputs

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu there is nothing related to it showing up!

Comment: maybe because of no violation??